# Converting to InputForm or StandardForm without deleting comments

Tags: inputfield, comment

Following on from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20143/updating-the-format-style-of-input-cells-from-older-noteboks) question: Is it possible to convert an expression to InputForm or StandardForm without losing the comments?

For example,

```
f[blah_] := Cos[blah] (* this is a comment *)
f[blah2_] := Cos[blah2] (* this is also a comment *)
```

selecting the cell and pressing Shift+Ctrl+N gives,

```
f[blah_] := Cos[blah] 
f[blah2_] := Cos[blah2]
```

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but there may be an undocumented function that does this.  [You never know.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/121)

Comment: How would you format, for example, `(Sum(* boo *))[x, x]` in standard form?

Comment: @Rojo I would like to turn it into a `ToolTip` :)

Comment: @Silvia then we want to convert it into SilviaForm :). Tooltip of the big sigma? I'm just thinking that the specifications are not so automatic

Comment: @Rojo `TemplateBox[{"x","boo",ToBoxes[f[x]]},"commentedSum",DisplayFunction:>(RowBox[{TooltipBox[UnderscriptBox["\[Sum]",#1],#2],#3}]&)]//RawBoxes` :) btw SilviaForm is a great name! I'll consider using it somewhere ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you highlight the code you wish to convert (one line at a time) and right click, then Convert To: this might be what your looking for.

Comment: Make Sure you do not highlight the comments.