# Unexpected result when reading Cell with comment-lines by NotebookRead

Tags: bugs, notebooks, boxes, comment

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

When considering [this question about re-formatting `Cell`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20143/17) (also [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20166/17)), I encountered an issue which confuses me. I'll let the code itself speak:

Consider the following simple `Cell` expression, which contains a comment line:

```
cellexpr = 
  Cell[BoxData[{RowBox[{RowBox[{"a", ";"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
       RowBox[{"(*", RowBox[{"b", ";"}], "*)"}]}], 
     "\[IndentingNewLine]", "c"}], "Input"];
```

Write it to a `Notebook`:

```
testnb = NotebookCreate[];
NotebookWrite[testnb, cellexpr];
```

It looks like the following, which is what one would expect:

[image]

Now read the `Cell` expression back from `testnb`:

```
SelectionMove[testnb, Before, Notebook];
SelectionMove[testnb, Next, Cell];
NotebookRead[testnb]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the first `RowBox`, it has a structure as `RowBox[ item1, item2, ...]`, which is ill-posed since *the first argument to RowBox must be a list*. And the obtained `Cell` expression is therefor ill-posed, which can be seen by `CellPrint`-ing it:

[image]

I noticed that if the comment-line part is removed (e.g. by deleting `"(*"` and `"*)"` in `cellexpr`), everything works fine. And for the example in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20166/17), the second comment is correctly obtained:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

## My question:

Did I miss something? Or is this a bug?

My system: **Mathematica 9.0.0.0** on **Windows 7 32-bit**

Comment: This may have been fixed in 9.0.1.  Please take a look at what I got with 9.0.1 on OS X: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8J6Oy.png

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the information! Now I begin to wonder when and why this wired bug..

Comment: This is very similar to a bug I encountered with Mathematica version 5 on windowsXP. The problem was : when I had a comment at the end of a cell, the cell became sometimes corrupted. A look inside the cell with ctrl-shift-E reveals a Row without List inside.

Comment: (follow the last comment) Maybe this problem has something to do with the fact there are two different characters * (see doc or ask details). These characters are very similar, but I saw at screen that the * in the (* was not the same as in *) (depending on system?)

Comment: @andre Hmm.. Interesting.. I never noticed there are two kinds of stars..

Comment: It was a bug, newly introduced to 9.0.0, and subsequently fixed in 9.0.1.  The same problem led to the oft-reported corruption of certain cells when you tired to merge them.

Comment: @JohnFultz Thank you! For fulfilling my curiosity! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20203/unexpected-result-when-reading-cell-with-comment-lines-by-notebookread#comment62374_20203), this was a bug:

> It was a bug, newly introduced to 9.0.0, and subsequently fixed in 9.0.1. The same problem led to the oft-reported corruption of certain cells when you tried to merge them.