# Problem when merging cells including commentary

Tags: bugs, formatting

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

This is a more of a problem report than a question. 
When merging the two cells
Cell1:

```
foo
(*foobar*)
bar
```

and Cell2:

```
foobar
```

the line immediately before the comment together with the comment line embark on a journey into another universe, leaving nothing behind than a vicious red box and the farewell greeting

"A RowBox with an invalid first argument was encountered. The first argument to RowBox must be a list."

*Mathematica* 9

Comment: upgrade to 9.0.1

Comment: Can confirm there is no problem with this on OS X with V9.0.1

Comment: I confirm this behavior on PC WinXP Math 9.0.1.0. The same behavior has been recently reported at the MathGroup site http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/

Comment: I've seen similar behavior before, but can't reproduce it at the moment. I suggest you contact support@wolfram.com.

Comment: @Rolf Does that mean this bug *was* present in v9.0.0?  If so I will tag it as such.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem in v9.0.1 on OS X.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20203/unexpected-result-when-reading-cell-with-comment-lines-by-notebookread#comment62374_20203)

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Do you mean [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/cell$20merge$20bug/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/BdWKj9ObuSs/tfRLnxiHjSsJ)  It was supposed to be fixed in 9.0.1, are you sure you still see this problem after upgrading?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes. `Button["Fix9", (NotebookWrite[#1, 
     NotebookRead[#1] //. 
      HoldPattern[RowBox[a_, b__]] :> RowBox[{a, b}]] & ) /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]]` is the simplest fix. Or `Import["http://www.mertig.com/mykeys.m"]` as mentioned in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/UQN1S_17Nq8/CEm3NF9qmLQJ)

Comment: @Szabolcs  yes, you are right, I meant that report. And you are right, it does not appear any more. I simply did not use Merge Cells command after having lost information with it once.

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful comments, I'll upgrade then.

Comment: I have the same problem on Mathematica v9.0.0 for Mac OS X!

Comment: I have no such problem with Mathematica 9.0.1 under Windows 7 x64.